# Wayland Issue on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, wayland, xdg

## The Problem

Hello, I am completely new to FreeBSD and relatively new to UNIX systems in general. I am following the FreeBSD Handbook, and loving it so far. My goal is to install river tiling window manager on Wayland. I am running into an issue, and from what I read in the handbook, I believe that this would have surfaced on *any other Wayland compositor as well.* **In short, the issue is with the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` not being valid/recognized.**

## Additional Info and Steps I Took

Hardware:

- Lenovo Thinkpad T480s
- Intel Core i7 8th Gen
- UHD Graphics 620
- 24 GB RAM

Software:

- FreeBSD 13.1-RELEASE
- Wayland 1.21.0
- River 0.2.4 (installed as a binary from the Latest port branch)

Steps I took so far while following the [Handbook's section on Wayland](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/wayland/#wayland-synopsis):

- Added the user to the video group:

  - `# pw groupmod video -m myUsername`
- Installed Wayland and a seat management daemon:

  - `# pkg install wayland seatd`
- Added to `.shrc`: *export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/var/run/user/`id -u`*
- Installed the appropriate graphics drivers:

  - `# pkg install drm-kmod`
- Then, added the module to `/etc/rc.conf` file by executing the following command:

  - `# sysrc kld_list+=i915kms`
- Installed the compositor:

  - `# pkg install river`
- Enabled and ran `seatd` as system service:

  - `# sysrc seatd_enable=”YES”`
  - `# service seatd start`
- Copied the [example configuration in posix shell](https://github.com/riverwm/river/blob/master/example/init) to: `~/.config/river/init`
- Started riverwm:

  - `# river`

## The Error

Here is the error output:

`info(wlroots): [wayland] error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment`

Clearly, the issue boils down to the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` not being recognized. I don't know what to do next. Here is what the Handbook had to say about it:

> It is important to note that most compositors will search the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` directory for the configuration files. In the examples included here, a parameter will be used to specify a configuration file in `~/.config` to keep temporary files and configuration files separate. It is recommended that an alias be configured for each compositor to load the designated configuration file.

However, river's documentation says this regarding where river gets the configuration files:

> On startup river will run an executable file at `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/river/init` if such an executable exists. If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set, `~/.config/river/init` will be used instead.

## The Question

Do I need to create `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`? Even though I defined it's path in my `.shrc`, `/var/run/user` does not exist on my system. If I need to create it, am I supposed to populate it with particular files? Clearly, Wayland expects it in order to start. River is not reporting any errors.

Any help here would be much appreciated! I would love for someone to point me to the right direction or fill in the gaps in my understanding of the system. Getting the solution would be great as well! :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to receive help from the creator of river's and other great users on [#river channel on irc.libera.chat](https://web.libera.chat/?channels=#river).

## The Solution

The only requirements of `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is that it exists and is owned by your user with 700 permissions.

In other words:

- Make a directory in `/var/run/user/` that bears a name of your user's id. In my case, it's `1001` (the output of `id -u`). Obviously, create the `user` directory in the first place if it does not exist.
- Once `/var/run/user/yourUserId` exists, make sure that your user is the owner of it and that the permissions are set to `700` (your user can `rwx` and no one else has any other permissions):

  - `# chown yourUsername /var/run/user/yourUserId`
  - `# chmod 700 /var/run/user/yourUserId`
- Add the following in your shell's rc file (Eg. .shrc, .bashrc):

  ```
  export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/var/run/user/`id -u`
  ```